# Query different tables based on status field value - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, left-join

I have a table named *user_requests* which contain user requests, with fields

```
id  title  user_id channel_type  programme_type  status
```

Field *status* can have values 0,1,3 or 4. What I need is to query different tables based on *channel_type* and the *status* field value.

1) If *channel_type* is 0 and *status* is 4, query table *channel_programmes* with fields,

```
id  title  request_id  channel_id
```

where *request_id* is the primary key of *user_requests*  table.

If *channel_type* is 1, also query table *videochannel* with fields

```
id  title  thumbnail
```

where the primary key *id* is referred as foreign key in table *channel_programmes* (*channel_id*).

2) If *channel_type* is 0 and *status* value is 0,1,2 or 3, query table *user_videos* with fields,

```
id channel_id videotitle
```

and table *videochannel* (as described ablove) if *channel_type* is 1.

I need the whole to be done in two separate queries. ie, one for *channel_type* with value as 0 and another for *channel_type* with value as 1.

Can anyone help me to find an appropriate query for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is usually accomplished with a union of the 2 tables and filtered by status value

Comment: try select ur.*, cp.*, vc.*, uv.* from user_requests as ur left join channel_programmes on cp.request_id = ur.id left join  videochannel as vc on vc.id = cp.channel_id left join user_videos as uv on uv.channel_id = cp.channel_id where ur.status =? (may be can help) use conditions or join according keys you have